# Adding Files dynamically to Chrome Extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have quite a popular chrome extension that adds features to Google+. One (quite new) feature of that is extension is a "QuickShare"-Feature offering sharing with a single click. This feature contains a lot of icons to choose from making my extension quite big (>10MB).

I heard complaints like "I won't install an extension that big, it will slow down my browser". While I am able to explain that this does not effect the stability or speed (they are just images only used when selected) I only can explain it to users who tell me so.

I expect a lot of users just saying nothing but not installing either.

To make it short:
The best way would be if I could remove the icons from the extension and only if someone really needs that feature offering a possibility to download the images. It would be ok, if the user has to install the "image pack" from the chrome web store but it has to be saved inside the main extensions' folder. (using its id)

Is there a way to achieve this? "just" downloading and saving the data myself would be prevented by the security model, I expect?

Comment: You might look into converting your images to an icon font. I have a site that had over 1MB of images reduced to under 10KB.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is not really an exact answer to your question but why don't you try to host the icons on a web-site?

You could create a pop-up dialog that would load the icons from your site and when a user chooses an icon you could load it with XMLHttpRequest, convert it to base64 with window.btoa() and store the resulting string in the storage. I believe the size of a single image is not that big. To embed it onto a page you could use data url thing.

Another option would be pack the images in a separate extension and then use cross-extension messaging to query them. Again it would have to be base64-encoded images because messages can not have binary data.

Just in case, [here](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/) is an article how to use data urls.

Comment: I already thought about the second solution but am unsure about performance issues which is quite important in my case

Comment: I think you could eliminate any performance issues by asking that separate extension to show the dialog with icons through cross-messaging. In that case the images will be loaded directly from disk. Then, after a user picks the icon that dedicated extension could send the the message back to the main extension with the data url of the selected image.